# Launching app from home screen will launch it on top of an existing instance if it was launched previously from the app screen, vise versa

Tags: android, google-play

There seems to be a bug of some sort with the play store installer, whenever I try to resume my app from the home screen icon rather than the app screen it will launch again on top of my already running app. This is true for the other way around

I've tried this code

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                && intentAction != null
                && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

But all it does it crash the app if it tries launching in the fashion I stated.

My manifest is also set to

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

I found that if I take exactly the same APK and install it using "adb install", my app works correctly and as I expect.

However, if I (or my users) download the apk and install it from the Downloads, I find the behaviour described above, namely a new instance of my Activity being created on the stack when the user navigates to home and then back to the app via the launcher.  This can be verified with "adb shell dumpsys activity "

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using the following at my Launch Activity

```
ublic class StartupActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (needStartApp()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    finish();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // this prevents StartupActivity recreation on Configuration changes 
    // (device orientation changes or hardware keyboard open/close).
    // just do nothing on these changes:
    super.onConfigurationChanged(null);
}

private boolean needStartApp() {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> tasksInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1024);

    if (!tasksInfo.isEmpty()) {
        final String ourAppPackageName = getPackageName();
        RunningTaskInfo taskInfo;
        final int size = tasksInfo.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            taskInfo = tasksInfo.get(i);
            if (ourAppPackageName.equals(taskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName())) {
                // continue application start only if there is the only Activity in the task
                // (BTW in this case this is the StartupActivity)
                return taskInfo.numActivities == 1;
            }
        }
    } 

    return true;
}
```

}